# Can't position React Native View at the bottom

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to position a React Native view at the bottom of my screen:

```
  <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.logout()}>
    <View style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 0 }}>
      <Text>{SignOut}</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
```

And the parent:

```
  <Fragment>
    <View>
      <ProfileSettings profile={this.state.profile} />
      <MainSettings data={this.state} />

    </View>
    <LogoutSettings />
  </Fragment>
```

And then the layout:

```
  <Fragment>
    <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
    <SafeAreaView>
      {/*<BackgroundProcess />*/}
      <Header />
      {this.props.children}
    </SafeAreaView>
  </Fragment>
```

As far as I can tell, this should get me all the way to the bottom...

However instead, my View centers right in the middle of the screen.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to position a view at the bottom of the screen? Plenty of tutorials say to use position absolute and bottom 0, but it does not appear to be working in my specific use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do it without position absolute . Add "flex:1" to view before "LogoutSettings" so it will have full height and "LogoutSettings" will be shown at bottom**

**Try this in parent**

```
<Fragment>
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <ProfileSettings profile={this.state.profile} />
      <MainSettings data={this.state} />
    </View>
    <LogoutSettings />
  </Fragment>
```

**Remove position absolute**

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.logout()}>
    <View >
      <Text>{SignOut}</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: Yep, that worked. I'm still getting the hang of flex in React. Most annoying is when I change styling and elements just straight up disappear. As far as I can tell that's due to not putting width and height on objects that are flexed. Anyway, that's off topic. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the style on `TouchableHighlight`, not `View`

```
  <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.logout()} style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 0 }}>
    <View>
      <Text>{SignOut}</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
```

You don't really need that `View` at all actually

Comment: Nope, even putting the styles on the TouchableHighlight, it's still right in the middle

Comment: Need more of your code, sounds like something else is conflicting

Comment: settingsHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height - 80; <View style={{ height: settingsHeight }}>

Comment: But that's literally my only structure - what I posted above, so I'm not sure why.